# Time complexity of this algorithm with steps on how to determine it mainly for line 4

Tags: time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
void programB(int n) {
    long prod = 1;
    for (int c=1;c<n;c=c*3)
        prod = prod * c;
```

I dont know how to calculate time complexity for the 3rd line of the code. Is it n^3?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sitting in a test and have the luxury of time, I always suggest trying some numbers:

```
n=10:
c = 1, 3, 9

n=20:
c = 1,3,9

n=30:
c=1,3,9,27
```

As you can see the number of iterations is not only less then `n^3`, it is much less than `n`. Basically you check how many times you can multiply 3 within `n` in this loop, which is my hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you had

```
void programB(int n) {
    long prod = 1;
    for (int c=1;c<=n;c=c+1)
        prod = prod * c;
```

this would run through the `n` things, so be O(n).

With

```
void programB(int n) {
    long prod = 1;
    for (int c=1;c<=n;c=c+1)
        for (int c=1;c<=n;c=c+1)
            prod = prod * c;
```

this runs through the `n` things for each of the `n` things, giving you O(n^2)

To get n^3 you need another for loop:

```
void programB(int n) {
    long prod = 1;
    for (int c=1;c<=n;c=c+1)
        for (int c=1;c<=n;c=c+1)
            for (int c=1;c<=n;c=c+1)
                prod = prod * c;
```

Your case doesn't do all of the `n` things, since it jumps in steps of `c=c*3`), giving powers of three, as shown in kabanus' answer: 1, 3, 9, 27... 
This gives you log_3 n, or O(log(n)) - since the base doesn't matter.

Comment: I think "The order is still O(n) though" is wrong. have a look at my answer. For `n=30` for example you predicted 10 iterations. The discrepancy will only get worse with `n`. For `n=300` you will have 6 iterations, not 100.

Comment: is it log n base 3

Comment: Yep - not paying attention.

Comment: @Manny Nice Manny.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity of this for loop is **log n base a**

```
int n,a;
    for(int c=1;c<n;c=c*a) 
    {
          //Some code
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, i have just copied from eclipse. Edited now. is this good? :-)